# how to throw java exception as jobject in JNI

Tags: c++, java-native-interface

I'm new in c++ and jni. I need to return java exception as jobject, not jint. I have a method which returns jobject. So I get compilation error when trying to return ThrowNew:

```
JNIEXPORT jobject JNICALL Java_com_my_get(JNIEnv* env, jobject obj) {
    some::SomeObject returnObject;
    try {
              //... trying to get returnObject by calling lib method
            returnObject = some::lib::getSomeObject();
          } catch (...) {
              // report problem back to Java.
              jclass Exception = env->FindClass("com/my/MyClientException");
              return env->ThrowNew(Exception, "Error");
          }

//... return returnObject mapped to jobject
}
```

java native part:

```
public native MyJavaObject get(); // need object or exception
```

Compilation error:

> error: invalid conversion from ‘jint’ {aka ‘int’} to ‘jobject’ {aka
> ‘_jobject*’} [-fpermissive]

How to do this? I need to stop the method when an error occurs.

Comment: ThrowNew returns an `jint`, but in the signature you say, that you return a `jobject`

Comment: Yes, I understand. May be some methods which returns java exception as jobject exists?

Comment: Use `Throw` and `NewObject`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't try to return the result of `ThrowNew` back to Java. Its return value only tells you whether the call succeeded. The [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/specs/jni/functions.html#thrownew) for `ThrowNew` states:

> RETURNS:
>
> Returns 0 on success; a negative value on failure.

Calling `ThrowNew` will cause control flow in the JVM to go to an exception handler upon return from the native method. Return any value you want after calling it; the value is ignored. For methods with a return type of `jobject`, simply return `nullptr`.

```
    env->ThrowNew(Exception, "Error");
    return nullptr;
```

Comment: @TainToTain Thanks, I thought so also. Maybe it is a good idea to return null, if there are no another options.

Comment: @rustyx Instead 'return env->ThrowNew' write 'env->ThrowNew...... ; return nullptr; ' Then you will catch MyClientException in java code. Use java try/catch